# CAML Query Multiple ORs (4) and an AND

Tags: caml

Sorry, probably an obvious one, but how do I do 4 ORs and an AND?

I know that 3 look like this

```
<And>
Many other Ands and Ors here
</And>
<Or>
    A
    <Or>
        B
        C
    </Or>
</Or>
```

but 4 seems to be pretty confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<And>
    <And>
        Many other Ands and Ors here
    </And>
    <Or>
        A
        <Or>
            B
            <Or>
                C
                D
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </Or>
</And>
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472196.aspx):

> The server supports unlimited complicated queries. However, any given Or element can have only two disjuncts; that is, only two child elements. If you need to disjoin three or more conditions, you must nest the Or elements